# In C, what values are equal to true or false when using them in an if statement's condition?

Tags: c

When I use if statement, I can get true or false using comparison (==) operator and values like integers, characters, etc. Please give me a complete list of values(please also mention what they yield, true or false) which can be used in if statement.

Comment: [All those values that can be implicitly casted to bool are fine.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very simple.

---

`0` is `False`

**EDIT suggested by [John Hascall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2040863/john-hascall)**

This includes `0` in all its forms (`0`, `'\0'`, `NULL`, `0.0`, `*""`, etc). Except `'0'` and `"0"`, which are TRUE because they really aren't `0`.

---

Any other value is taken as `True`

Comment: This includes `0` in all its forms (0, '\0', NULL, 0.0, *"", etc).  Except '0' and "0", which are TRUE because they really aren't 0.

Answer (score 4):

In C everything !=0 is true.
0 is false.

A NULL pointer (==0) is false this yelds to many simplifications that sometimes make less understandable C language statements.
I.e

```
int *p;
....
if (p)
    ....
```

In the code above the pointer check `if(p!=NULL)` has been simplified.
This, even if not strictly correct, works for almost all C versions, pre-ansi up to C90 equates a null pointer to a null value in expression, while C99 and C11 clearly states (par. 6.3.2.3 Pointers, point 3):

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant. If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>   pointer to any object or function.

Comment: ^ This. Essentially, `if(x)` is _always_ equivalent to `if((x) != 0)` recursively, so anything comparing unequal to `0` (whether number or pointer) is true.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Yes, exactly. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: A _null pointer_ is not thje same as the macro `NULL`. And it has not necessarily the _value_ `0`. But it compares equal to and _null pointer constant_ or any other _null pointer_ of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Anything can be used in `if` like this `if(value)`. Value can be of any type.
You need to be careful when using `if(a == b)`. In this case, a and b use be compatible otherwise, it can give compile time error. You definitely need to look out for runtime compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, 0 is false and anything else is true. Short example:

```
int a = 0, b = 1, c = 256;

if(a) printf("a is true \n");
else  printf("a is false \n");

if(b) printf("b is true \n");
else  printf("b is false \n");

if(c) printf("c is true \n");
else  printf("c is false \n");
```

the output would be:

```
a is false
b is true 
c is true
```